# C: Accessing an array in another file creates Segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

i'm trying to read values from a .csv file and write them in another .txt file. But when i'm trying to pass the values it creates a Segmentation fault.

My first program, which filters the needed values from the .csv file:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Aufruf: %s <anzahl> <bundesland>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Beispiel: %s 100 Bayern\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Klein-/Großschreibung beachten!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int anzahl = atoi(argv[1]);
    char *bundesland = argv[2];

    // Statisch allokierter Speicher
    char staedte[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    char laender[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    int bewohner[MAX_LAENGE_ARR];

    int len = read_file("staedte.csv", staedte, laender, bewohner);

    // Hier implementieren
    char** result = malloc(MAX_LAENGE_ARR * sizeof(char *));
    if (result == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed while allocating memory");
        exit(1);
        } 
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (strcmp(bundesland, laender[i]) == 0 && *bewohner > anzahl) {
            result[i] = malloc(MAX_LAENGE_STR * sizeof(char *));
            if (result == NULL) {
                perror("malloc failed while allocating memory");
                exit(1);
            }
            snprintf(result[i], MAX_LAENGE_STR, "Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner.", staedte[i], bewohner[i]);
            write_file(&result[i], len);
            free(result[i]);
        }
    } 

    // Mithilfe von write_file(...) soll das Ergebnis in die "resultat.txt"
    // geschrieben werden. 
    // Dynamisch allozierter Speicher muss hier freigegeben werden.
}
```

And the faulting part of my second program, which should write the handed values from the first program into a .txt file:

```
int MAX_LAENGE_STR = 255;
int MAX_LAENGE_ARR = 100;

void write_file(char *result[], int len) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("resultat.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL){
        perror("resultat.txt");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        printf("<write_file> loop[%d]: %s\n", i, result[i]);
        fprintf(fp, "%p\n", result[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

It creates a Segmentation fault in the 11th loop, in the write_file(), and i can't figure out why. In valgrind it's: "Invalid read size of 1".

Comment: Isn't result[i] a char*. You don't need to pass its address to write_file, just pass it directly. Also, instead of allocating ``MAX*sizeof(char*)`` when creating buffer for a string, use ``MAX*sizeof(char)``.

Comment: Also what is `*bewohner > anzahl`? `*bewohner` is the first element of your int array `bewohner` so same as `bewohner[0]`. Is that really what you want to compare? Maybe `bewohner[i]`but I don't know your logic here.

Comment: *bewohner is one of the values in my .csv file. With this comparison i want to compare an input to the contents of my .csv file. This part is working perfectly fine, and i'm able to run my program perfectly fine with just: `printf("%s", result[i]);`. But when trying to hand over the values to the second program and write those values into a txt file it crashes with the segmentation fault. And i'm not allowed to change the second program due to my prof, because thats my limitation.

Comment: Please use English-looking identifiers and messages. provide some [MCVE]. Compile with all warnings and debug info : `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. **Use the debugger** `gdb`

Answer (score 2):

1. `result[i] = malloc(MAX_LAENGE_STR * sizeof(char *));`

should be

```
result[i] = malloc(MAX_LAENGE_STR * sizeof(char));
```

`sizeof(char)` is by definition all the time 1, even if char is represented on more than 8 bits, which is the minimal required by the definition of C.  So you can avoid writing it here.

---

2. `write_file(&result[i], len);`

should be

```
write_file(result[i], length(result[i]) );
```

as you allocated `MAX_LAENGE_STR` for `result[i]`

and change the signature of write_file to

```
void write_file(char *result, int len)
```

as you want to pass a single string as parameter.

---

3. `printf("<write_file> loop[%d]: %s\n", i, result[i]);`

should be

```
printf("<write_file> loop[%d]: %c\n", i, result[i]);
```

because you want to print the ith char in result, all the string once.

---

4. `fprintf(fp, "%p\n", result[i]);`

should be

```
fprintf(fp, "%c\n", result[i]);
```

as `result[i]` is `char`, not pointer.

There are other things to say, first correct these ones.

Comment: when i'm removing the '&' from the result. i'm getting a compiler warning, that i'm passing an incompatible pointer type. And the fprintf() cannot be changed by me, thats a regulation.

Comment: write_file should take a ``char*`` or ``char x[]``; not ``char* x[]`` as that is an array of strings.

Comment: @ChristianSteuer yes, you need to change the signature of write_file as well.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is **always** 1. No need to write that.